# Matching 2 columns with 2 others columns to return a value from another column

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, vlookup

I have an issue I'm trying to fix in excel.
I want to create an automation with the following logic:
-Lookup each value from column H and I
-If they match the values in column A and B respectively
-Return the value in C to column J.

** Basically, IF(((H=A) AND (I=B)) THEN (return C in J))  **** 
How is that possible?

Comment: Are multiple matches possible?

Answer (score 1):

In J2:

```
=IF(AND(H2=A2, I2=B2), C2, "")
```

Comment: Hey Tim
But that's the thing... 
The value can be anything in the column not limited to the row...
I need the combination of H and I to be the same as A and B so it can return C in J.

Answer (score 1):

In J2 this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$100,MATCH(H2 & "|" & I2,$A$2:$A$100 & "|" & $B$2:$B$100,0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

So enter in J2.  Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy down.